# Create own ethereum wallet and web app

Tags: go-ethereum, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I am new for ethereum and I have a few knowledge in ethereum token. I
already created my own custom cryptocurrency using ethereum wallet app.

Now I want to integrate it with my app for transaction and all. And
also want a user interface to manage wallet money/token for sending,
receiving, balance for all users.

Answer (score 3):

I strongly recommend you to study Solidity and Javascript, in order to write your own smart contracts and the user interface, you can find a good amount of information about solidity here [Solidity Documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/).

About the user interface, is recommended to use the [Ethereum JavaScript API - Web3](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API), it's used to connect your interface with the Ethereum Blockchain, using javascript. You can also use any framework you wish, for example: React and Angular.

Tools that I use and recommend to develop smart contracts:

1. [Remix](https://remix.ethereum.org/) (Web Ide)
2. [Truffle Network](http://truffleframework.com) (Test and compile the smart contracts)
3. [Geth](https://github.com/hiddentao/geth-private) (Run TestRPC network)
4. [MetaMask](https://metamask.io/) (Browser to run dapps without running a node)
5. [Mist Wallet](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases) (Ethereum wallet)

Comment: Mist is deprecated now.